# creat random number in double format, eclipse stop working

Tags: c++, c

generate random number 0-1, when I type the input number less than 4, the code works fine.    However when the input number above 4, the eclipse stop working. what's wrong with my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
double ran(double x0, double x1){
return x0+(x1-x0)*rand()/((double)RAND_MAX);
}
int main(void) {
int a,i;
double *b;
printf("input the size\n");
scanf("%d", &a);
b=(double*)malloc(sizeof(int)*a);
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
    b[i]=ran(0,1);
    printf("\n %f", b[i]);
}
free (b);
return 1;

}
```

Comment: [don't cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double is bigger than an integer. A double is eight bytes, while an integer is 4 bytes.
You should replace

```
b = (double*)malloc(sizeof(int)*a);
```

with

```
b = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*a);
```

or even better (thaks to [Lưu Vĩnh Phúc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995714/l%C6%B0u-v%C4%A9nh-ph%C3%BAc))

```
b = malloc(a * sizeof b[0]);
```

Comment: better `b = malloc(a * sizeof b[0]);`